# IE rotation off axis

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            var rotation = 'rotate('+$(document).scrollTop()+'deg)';
            things.css({
                '-webkit-transform' : rotation,
                '-moz-transform'    : rotation,
                '-ms-transform'     : rotation,
                '-o-transform'      : rotation,
                'transform'         : rotation
            });
        });
```

This code rotates the elements on a page well when I call it, except in IE where the elements rotate off-axis.

Comment: Could it potentially be that `scrollTop()` in IE should be applied to the window and not the document? I've had that issue before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) value to position the center point of the rotation

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: I was about to post this but this is it, mostly. Though when you say `center`, your values should be `center` as well (aka `50% 50%`)... Heres a good find for anyone who reads this: https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie

Comment: Yes, if you want to position the centre point of the rotation on the centre of the element then you would use 50% 50%

Comment: Actually, @Jackson, as the link points out, IE is different from all browser with the fact that its point is `0, 0`. To achieve the result the question asked for, a `50%, 50%` would be the best answer possible as it puts IE on parity with the other browsers, which is what the question was about.

Comment: Fixed but I can't accept my own answer, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The fix laid in a class I had in the element! It was a icon font element.

```
line-height: 1;
```

needed to be changed to

```
line-height: normal;
```